# C# bulkcopy to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

Hoping someone can help me understand what I've got wrong here. I have confirmed the data is in the datatable, and that the SQL Server connection works. But I can't seem to push the data into the temp table (or at least I can't see it once I have).

I have looked at various post about using the bulkcopy function, but I must be missing something as it just does not appear to working.

The script runs with no errors, but I cannot see the temp table in the DB after the script runs.

Any help in working out where I've gone wrong is much appreciated.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employees");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("LastName");

foreach (var employee in context.Employees.AsEnumerable())
{
    dt.Rows.Add(employee.Name, employee.LastName);
}

Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0]["Name"]);

Console.WriteLine("Loading data into SQL");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=<ID>;" +
                                              "password=<Password>;server=<Server>;" +
                                              "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                              "database=<DB>; " +
                                              "connection timeout=30"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", conn))
    {
        try
        {
             conn.Open();

             // Creating temp table on database
             command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE ##TmpTable(...)";
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();

             // Bulk insert into temp table
             using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
             {
                 bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 660;
                 bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "##TmpTable";
                 bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                 bulkcopy.Close();
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Bulk load to SQL failed");// Handle exception properly
         }
         finally
         {
             conn.Close();
             Console.WriteLine("table loaded into SQL");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to verify if data is bulk copied or not? Are you getting any error while running the code?

Comment: No errors. I am querying the db separately for that particular table

Comment: Instead of using temp table try creating a proper table in database and bulk copy into that. If that works that means bulk copy doesn't work with temp tables.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have permission to create tables in the DB, ergo why i'm using a temp table

Comment: Can't you use local sql server installed in your machine? Sample code you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In theory yes I could use a local DB to prove whether or not the bulk upload works with a temp table. But I have already seen various posts where people have used temp tables (just my code does not seem to be working). In the end I will have to access this particular server, as I will be making use of data already on that server after this is loaded in.

Comment: _[Global temporary tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables) are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended._

Comment: *Global Temporary tables name starts with a double hash ("##"). Once this table has been created by a connection, like a permanent table it is then available to any user by any connection. It can only be deleted once all connections have been closed.* - Doesnt this mean that if I maintain a connection to a db the global temp table will not get dropped until all connections end? I am maintaining a connection to the DB through SSMS.

Comment: @Calum : From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx#Anchor_1),*Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.* So, I believe, it's your connection from code that need to be exist. So, from simple test, you should able to get all data from that global temporary variable using same connection.

Comment: No, your code creates the table, that is its context: _The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table **when the creating session** ended._

Comment: You can try querying the temp table before you close/dispose your `conn` above.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I did a query for the temp table within the connection. You are correct, its there and then gone once the connection drops.

Comment: Have a think about whether you really need to use a temp table. Often you can just use whats generally referred to as a "staging" table - just a normal table where data processing takes place before data is loaded into the real table. The only reason to not use this approach is if you have a bunch of parallel processes using this table at the same time. If a single planned scheduled process is doing this work, a staging table is ideal (and you can leave it full of data afterwards for debugging / auditing)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem during WPF programming...You need to create a mapping between source datatable's columns and destination table's columns. I don't know exactly why it needs to be done after mentioning the destination's table name which should be enough...however the following code worked for me...

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Device_GameDevice", sqlConn, transaction) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
                                {
 SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapstep = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Message", "Message");
  SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping maptran = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("DeviceName", "DeviceName");
 SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapstt = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("dt_datetime", "dt_datetime");
 SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapfunc = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("GameName", "GameName");

 sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(mapstep);
 sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(maptran);
 sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(mapstt);
 sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(mapfunc);

 sqlBulk.DestinationTableName ="Device_GameDevice";

sqlBulk.WriteToServer(resultantDataTableForMaxDate);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

transaction.Commit();

 }
```

Hope this helps...:)

Comment: This example doesn't use a temp table so it's quite different

Comment: Yes..but the main point of posting this example was to show how column mapping is done...since Calumn was wondering about why sqlbulk copy did not work, I believe column mapping needed to be included....Thanks for pointing it out...:)

Comment: I agree that you should always specify mappings rather than assume they'll map correctly - good point, I missed that bit

Answer (score 0):

If you close Connection then you never find Has(#) Tables in Database.
If you want your data in sql server then you need to open you connection and don't close while you using your ##temptable. After when you done work with your ##temptable then close connection. ##tepmtable automatically remove from database.

Thank you,